# Avoiding double taxation during transfer of funds from India to US

Tags: usa, taxes, indian-citizens, tax-treaties

If my parents send me money, what is the procedure to do so without the (already tax-paid in India) funds coming under double taxation? Would I have to declare such 'income' and if so what is the process to indicate it is a gift and avail of any taxation treaties between US & India?

I am currently on a U.S. Green Card, if I switch to US citizenship in future how would this affect the situation?

Comment: US taxation is essentially the same for green card holders and citizens.

Answer (score 1):

Money received as a gift might not be income, under the IRS rules. In general, income is money received for work or through investments. The [IRS is very clear: income from abroad is taxable](https://www.irs.gov/businesses/income-from-abroad-is-taxable), for both resident aliens and US citizens.

Your individual circumstances will determine whether you need to consult a tax attorney to ensure that you are reporting accurately and within the law.

Comment: Gifts are certainly income.  They are *unearned* income, as opposed to earned income.  Gifts are subject to special tax treatment, so the advice to consult a tax professional is well heeded, but the curious stack exchange user may find some answers at [money.SE].